# Is my assumption for thinner limbs on race horses / hounds correct?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, acceleration, biology

My assumption -as a layman- is that thinner limbs (given equal compared length on *normal* animal limbs) can accelerate faster due to their reduced mass i.e. [unsprung weight transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Car_suspension#Unsprung_weight_transfer) in regards to [g-Force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-force)

1. Is my assumption correct?
2. Do the provided Wikipedia links provide a valid explanation of my assumption to other laymen?

Comment: I mean they will accelerate faster for a given force I guess. But I think that's missing the point a bit since you can "always" increase the force behind it. I think the more important point is that they will experience less stresses so can accelerate faster before failing structurally.

Answer (score 2):

In general, strength varies approximately with cross-sectional area $A$ while mass varies with volume. Volume varies approximately with the product of cross-sectional area $A$ and length $L$.

Limb acceleration varies linearly with strength and inversely with mass. Running speed varies linearly with limb acceleration and limb length.

It follows that running speed varies approximately as $aAL/m = bAL/AL = b$ for some constants a, b.

That is: neither limb thickness nor limb length should change running speed as a first-order effect.

Thick limbs are costly both in terms of the energy required to run and the raw materials required to build them. Thick limbs also require powerful torsos and hips to drive them and sturdy bone structures to support the muscle system. All this mass slows acceleration of the animal (although not its top speed), costs energy to move around, and costs raw materials to build.

Thus we should expect animals that need to run a lot to have long, slender limbs because they are more efficient, even absent any speed advantage.

If we need to treat limbs as anything more complicated than magically self-accelerating cross-section powered cylinders, a first-principles physics approach will be difficult. Some other physics things to consider, though:

Longer limbs can potentially support muscles with more leverage thanks to connection points farther from joints, therefore allowing greater strength at the same cross-sectional area.

A lot of running fast is spent in the air. A larger animal can get more air time per stride than a smaller animal.

Comment: So to speak as layman in *a first-principles physics approach*: Given two scenarios, only differing by the cylinder weighing less due to it's smaller radius (everything else in the scenario is equal). Does the lighter cylinder accelerate faster?

Comment: @jjk Yes, absolutely - if the smaller magic cylinder (or the more slender limb) would have the same ability to exert forces despite being smaller, it would accelerate faster.

Answer (score -1):

Animals that run tend to have thinner and longer legs, among other things.

This is from [Cheetah vs Leopard](https://www.thewildlifediaries.com/cheetah-vs-leopard/#Cursory_hunter_vs_ambush_hunter)

[image]

You can see the same thing when you compare a coyote to a wolf.